# Why is sfPropelORM breaking my form filter criteria?

Tags: mysql, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

I was using the sfPropel15Plugin with Symfony 1.3.11, and everything was working great.

I decided to upgrade the plugin to the sfPropelORMPlugin, which uses Propel 1.6.
I did the normal steps to install the plugin.  I was able to get the app back up and working
in most cases.  However, I find that certain form filter criteria I was using before are now breaking and not generating valid sql.

Here's an example that works in 1.5, but not 1.6:

```
// select only users who are sales reps on an existing quote
$c = new Criteria();
$c->addJoin(sfGuardUserPeer::ID, sfGuardUserProfilePeer::USER_ID);
$c->addJoin(QuotePeer::SALESREP, sfGuardUserPeer::ID);
$c->addGroupByColumn(sfGuardUserPeer::ID);
$c->addAscendingOrderByColumn(sfGuardUserProfilePeer::FIRST_NAME);

$this->widgetSchema['salesrep'] = new sfWidgetFormPropelChoice(array(
  'label'     => 'Sales rep',
  'add_empty' => true,
  'order_by'  => array('Username', 'asc'),
  'model'     => 'sfGuardUser',
  'method'    => 'getFullName',
  'criteria'  =>  $c,
  'key_method'=> 'getId',
  'multiple'  => false
));
```

Which generates this invalid MySQL:

```
SELECT sf_guard_user.ID, sf_guard_user.USERNAME, sf_guard_user.ALGORITHM, sf_guard_user.SALT, sf_guard_user.PASSWORD, sf_guard_user.CREATED_AT, sf_guard_user.LAST_LOGIN, sf_guard_user.IS_ACTIVE, sf_guard_user.IS_SUPER_ADMIN, sf_guard_user.VANTIVE_ID FROM LEFT JOIN `sf_guard_user` ON (quote.SALES_ENGINEER=sf_guard_user.ID)
```

Mostly I'd like to determine if this is a bug, if I can fix it with a minor change, or if I should roll back to 1.5.

Comment: have you tried `$c->setPrimaryTableName('sfGuardUser)`?

Comment: I haven't yet.  Never had to use it before, but sounds appropriate.